# Correct routing for Yii functional tests

Tags: selenium, yii

I try to run tests with Selenium for my Yii application. A simple test where i open the entry page and check for a text is working.

Let's take the following test snippet:

```
class ItemTest extends WebTestCase
{
    public function testCreateItem()
    {
        $this->open('admin/item');
        $this->click("link=create item...");
              ...
    }
}
```

"admin" is a module in my app. The first function open() is working. The correct url with index-test.php is called.

But the second function click() is somehow routed to the main index.php and not to index-test.php. I guess it has to do with my url manager configuration?

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    'urlFormat'=>'path',
'rules'=>array(
    ''=>'site/index',
    '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
    '<module:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<module>/<controller>/<action>',
    '<module:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<module>/<controller>/<action>',
),
'showScriptName'=>false,
),
```

I would be glad if you could give me some tips how it would be best to handle this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your config/test.php you have to tell it to show script file name (index-test.php):

```
return CMap::mergeArray(
    require(dirname(__FILE__).'/main.php'),
    array(
        'components'=>array(
            'fixture'=>array(
                'class'=>'system.test.CDbFixtureManager',
            ),
            /* uncomment the following to provide test database connection
            'db'=>array(
                'connectionString'=>'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db-test',
            ),
            */
            'urlManager' => array(
                'showScriptName' => true,
            ),
        ),
    )
);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that's working. Shame on me that I did not figgure that out.